# Дата и время UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Столкнулся с проблемой байдинга даты и времени. Идея такая: дата выбирается в CalendarDatePicker, а время указывается в TimePicker. Пробовал осуществлять привязку в DateTime, но ничего из этого не вышло. Каким образом можно осуществить привязку даты и времени к одному компоненту, без применения обработчиков событий?

Comment: Что значит «ничего не вышло»? Что вы написали, что получилось фактически, и что вы ожидали?

Comment: @VladD При попытке привязки TimePicker к DateTime, возникала ошибка, а студия требовала в качестве объекта привязки TimeSpan, но после привязки, при попытке выбрать дату, программа падала. Думал что с null object проблема, поэтому использовал TimeSpan?. С календарем, в качестве объекта привязки, студия потребовала DateTimeOffset. А по итогу, к общему знаменателю не пришел.

Comment: Ага, и правда, [ему нужен TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TimePicker_Time). С DateTime не выйдет.

Comment: @VladD Требует TimeSpan, но при попытке выбора времени - падает. А к TimeSpan? он не привязывается, требует not nullable версию. Как тогда можно совместить значение TimePicker и DateTimeOffset самым безболезненным способом?

Comment: А по какой причине падает? Вы даёте ему TimeSpan? Может, ошибка где-то ещё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте положить в VM *два* свойства: одно для даты, одно для времени. Получится как-то так:

```
DateTimeOffset justday;
TimeSpan justtime;

public DateTimeOffset JustDay
{
    get => justday;
    set =>
    {
        if (justday != value)
        {
            justday = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Date));
        }
    }
}

public TimeSpan JustTime
{
    get => justtime;
    set =>
    {
        if (justtime != value)
        {
            justtime = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Date));
        }
    }
}

public DateTime Date => day.Date + time;
```

К `CalendarDatePicker`'у привязывайте `JustDay`, к `TimePicker`'у — `JustTime`. Результат читайте в `Date`.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, все работает как надо, за исключением использования местного времени. Но это дело поправимое :)

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов: Рад, что помогло! А в чём проблема? Результат получается в местном времени, а вам нужно абсолютное?

Comment: все оказалось проще: при сложении даты и времени, добавляются часы к текущему времени, поэтому и происходит искажение. Я сделал просто: присвоил часы и минуты из JustTime к Date. Но я думаю это все из-за того, что компилятор потребовал для календаря DateTimeOffset.

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов: А если так: `public DateTime Date => day.Date + time;`?

Comment: Да, заработало. Ещё раз большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов: Пожалуйста! Внёс в ответ.

Comment: Как вариант, можно сделать наоборот - `DateTime Date` хранимое, а 2 свойства вычисляемые

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Тогда непонятно, что биндить к picker'у, если два свойства read-only.

Comment: Почему read-only? С сеттерами, чуть-чуть замороченными, правда

Comment: @АндрейNOP: А, в этом смысле? Тогда конечно, можно и так, и так. Мне путь с двумя свойствами показался концептуально проще.